# Distinct selection with CouchDB and elasticsearch

Tags: couchdb, elasticsearch

I have this CouchDB/[elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) setup. CouchDB as a storage, elasticsearch for search.

I need to execute this query,

```sql
select distinct name from table
```

in this *"table"*

```js
[
  {name:'david' ... more data},
  {name:'david' ... more data},
  {name:'alex' ... more data}
  {name:'alex' ... more data}
]
```

to get this:

```js
  ['david', 'alex']
```

or this:

```js
  [
      {name:'david'},
      {name:'alex'}
  ]
```

or in whatever form but the result of a distinct query.

Using CouchDB it can be done by this:

```js
// map
function(doc) {
    emit(doc.name);
}

// reduce
function(keys, values) {
   return null;
}
```

But I want to use elasticsearch to do it. There is some info on the web but is not clear.

Can someone point me in the right direction to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [Terms Facet Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/terms-facet.html) on the field `name`.

Comment: So the query looks like this?

{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {  }
    },
    "facets" : {
        "tag" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "name",
                "size" : 10
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: Yes, if you want only 10 most frequently occurring names. If you want more than 10, you will need to increase the value of the `size` parameter.

Comment: Yes, it does return all records as well, you can suppress it by adding "size": 0 on the top level or by adding &search_type=count to the url. The fields will can be found in the "facets" element that typically appears after the records.